# In-page suggested edit review not visible when visiting page from comment link

Tags: bug, comments, review, suggested-edits

It's possible to review suggested edits 'in-page', when you see an 'edit (1)' link under a post you can click on it and review the suggested edit.
However, when you visit a page from a comment link, e.g. right now [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-do-i-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it/830467#comment6970072_805589), 
scroll down to the post with a suggested edit and click that link, the entire screen goes black:

[image]

You can scroll down further to get to the actual dialog:

[image]

but since this is a rather long question, it's far from obvious. If you use a link without an anchor, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547) it works as expected.

(Reproduced on Puzzling.SE and Stack Overflow, in both Firefox and Safari on macOS. The example above might not work anymore if the edit is reviewed, but it's fairly easy to find another suggested edit on a long Q&A via the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/).)